# Get only production dependencies from .yarn/cache to build Docker image

Tags: docker, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I would to build a Docker image using multi-stage.
We are using yarn 2 and Zero installs feature which stores dependencies in .yarn/cache under zip format.

To minimize the size of my Docker image, I would like to only have the production dependencies.
Previsously, we would do

```
yarn install  --non-interactive --production=true
```

But by doing that with a former version of yarn, we don't benefit from the .yarn/cache folder and it takes time to download dependencies whereas there are already here but not readable by the former version of yarn.

Is there a way to tell yarn 2 to get only production dependencies from the .yarn/cache folder and put it into another one ? Thus I could copy this folder inside my image and save time and space.